# php.ini settings do not make sessions to secure

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have configured php.ini settings like below and using a PHP 7.4.

```
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.cookie_samesite =
```

But these setting do not add Secure flag for cookies to true.

I see this error on console:

```
Cookie “__tld__” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute.
```

And I made Jira Cloud App and Jira Cloud is in different sever than my App. Everything works fine with Firefox but not with Chrome or Edge.

What do?

Comment: Does the setting reflect in phpinfo()?

Comment: Yes. on phpinfo(); has a cookie_secure 1.

Comment: Which cookie is missing the secure flag then? This setting only affects `PHPSESSID` which is set by PHP itself. If you want other cookies to have this flag, you need to specify it when setting the cookie in your code...

Comment: This setting is session.name = PHPSESSID.

Comment: There is no relationship between the cookie `__tld__` and the php ini file settings in the question. You need to look in your application code for the string `__tld__` and go from there.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the message you show isn't actually saying that the cookie _has been_ rejected, only that it _will be in a future version of the browser_. So if you have something not working _right now_, it's not because of that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows a warning for a cookie called `__tld__`, but your comments indicate that you have the default *session cookie name* of `PHPSESSID`.

So this cookie is not created by [PHP's session management functionality](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), and will not be affected by those settings. Sessions and cookies are not the same thing, and there is no evidence that this cookie has anything to do with sessions.

You need to find where in the code the `__tld__` cookie is being set. If it is in your PHP application, it will probably be via a call to [the `setcookie` function](https://www.php.net/setcookie), which takes additional options to specify the "HttpOnly", "SameSite" and "Secure" attributes.

Cookies can also be set from JavaScript, or by third-party advertising and tracking scripts which you include in your page.

Comment: On my App has only lines: if (!Zend_Session::namespaceGet(str_replace(array('https://', '.atlassian.net'), array('', ''), $request->getParam('xdm_e')).'-customer')) {
   $customer = new Zend_Session_Namespace(str_replace(array('https://', '.atlassian.net'), array('', ''), $request->getParam('xdm_e')).'-customer');
   $customer->domain = str_replace('https://', '', $request->getParam('xdm_e'));
  } else {
   
  }
  
  $instance = new Zend_Session_Namespace('instance');
  $instance->instance = str_replace(array('https://', '.atlassian.net'), array('', ''), $request->getParam('xdm_e'));

Comment: @MattiKiviharju I'm guessing that's not actually *all the code in your app*, but that you searched for "session". Just to make it absolutely clear, **your problem has nothing to do with sessions**. You have a **cookie** - set by your PHP code, or maybe even some JS code, called `__tld__`. That is what you need to find.

Comment: I noticed that Chrome makes 2 empty session files session folder and 1 session file with data.

Comment: @MattiKiviharju You're still insisting on looking in the wrong place. **Sessions and cookies are not the same thing**. Sessions are a piece of storage on, and entirely controlled by, PHP on the server; Chrome has no control over them. Sessions *use* cookies as a way to communicate with the browser, but **other code can use cookies as well, which has nothing to do with sessions**. There is **no reason at all** to assume that the cookie giving the error has any relationship with sessions whatsoever.

Comment: Everything worked fine on my old server but to work on my new server.

Comment: @MattiKiviharju There really isn't anything more to say: you have to find where that `__tld__` cookie is coming from, and go from there. If you find it but don't know how to fix it, ask a new question.

Comment: I want to tell how my App working. On first page load it makes a cookie with name customer and writes it to session file. On me old sever everything worked fine with php.ini settings session.cookie_secure = 1 but not with session.cookie_secure = 0. Also on my old sever PHP version was 7.3.